# Application Crashes after pressing the get button. Remote Database from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to connect to a remote database from android. I want to give a name as an input. My app should displays the row containing that name. I followed androidhive tutorials to achieve this. My app opens, after i enter the name it crashes please help me out.My main activity is as follows:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText branchname;
    EditText counters;
    EditText tokensserved;
    EditText tokensissued;
    EditText tokenswaiting;
    Button btnGet;


    String branch;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_product_detials = "http://10.0.2.2/android/getdata.php";


    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_BRANCH = "branchname";
    private static final String TAG_COUNTERS= "counters";
    private static final String TAG_SERVED = "tokensserved";
    private static final String TAG_ISSUED = "tokenissued";
    private static final String TAG_WAITING="tokenswaiting";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // save button
        btnGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGet);


        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        branch = i.getStringExtra(TAG_BRANCH);



        // save button click event


        // Delete button click event
        btnGet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // deleting product in background thread
                new GetProductDetails().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branchname", branch));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            branchname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.branchname);
                            counters = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.counters);
                            tokensserved = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tokensserved);
                            tokensissued=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tokensissued);    
                            tokenswaiting=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tokenswaiting);
                            // display product data in EditText
                            branchname.setText(product.getString(TAG_BRANCH));
                            counters.setText(product.getString(TAG_COUNTERS));
                            tokensserved.setText(product.getString(TAG_SERVED));
                            tokensissued.setText(product.getString(TAG_ISSUED));
                            tokenswaiting.setText(product.getString(TAG_WAITING));


                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

My JSONParser

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Name Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="Branch Name"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <!-- Input Name -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/branchname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <!-- Price Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="counters"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <!-- Input Price -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/counters"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <!-- Description Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="Served"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <!-- Input description -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tokensserved"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:lines="4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="Issued"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <!-- Input description -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tokensissued"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:lines="4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="Waiting"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

    <!-- Input description -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tokenswaiting"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:lines="4" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- Button Create Product -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGet"
            android:layout_width="111dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Get" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the logcat:

```
06-10 17:18:02.184: W/dalvikvm(1607): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a2fba8)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607): Process: com.example.androidhive, PID: 1607
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.example.androidhive.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.example.androidhive.MainActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(MainActivity.java:120)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-10 17:18:02.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1607):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My PHP:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["branchname"])) {
    $branchname = $_GET['branchname'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM branches WHERE branchname = $branchname");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();

            $product["branchname"] = $result["branchname"];
            $product["counters"] = $result["counters"];
            $product["tokensserved"] = $result["tokensserved"];
                        $product["tokenissuedd"] = $result["tokensissued"];
                                    $product["tokenswaiting"] = $result["tokenswaiting"];

            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $branch);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I will be extremely grateful to any one who can help me. i have spent many sleepless nights over this. thank you.I am using WAMP server and phpmyadmin. My database contains 5 fields branchname, counters,served,issued,waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

You're not even running the httprequest on a background thread, you're running it on the main UI thread. As @andreasrs mentioned, this is not allowed in Android. All httprequests must be done in another thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. But the problem was in php. I added error-reporting (0) at the beginning and it works

Answer (score 0):

The app crashing is not related to your PHP code.

The problem is the Android/Java application.
You are attempting to access the network on the **same thread** that draws the user interface. This is bad practice, and an exception is thrown like you see in your stacktrace.

To fix it, you can do the network request in an AsyncTask. The app will not crash in the same way once you do the networking in a separate thread.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: The PHP code itself should be updated as it is vulnerable to injection. I have not looked at it very closely. But the app crashing will be fixed by moving the network operations to an AsyncTask as stated in the answer.